# Add custom plots to plot catalog in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I've just noticed the plot catalog in R2011a. Does anyone know how to add my own plot functions to it?

http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2011/04/18/redesigned-plot-catalog-in-matlab-r2011a/

BTW, I'm pretty sure it has something to do with plotpickerlayout.xml, but I can't find any information about it.

Comment: That's a good question.  I never thought about adding to the catalog - just had my own functions.

Comment: check this page: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-type-selection-components/

Comment: @Amro. I think that that talks about how to get information _out of_ the plot catalog. I'd like to be able to get information _into_ it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scott Hirsch, Matlab’s lead product manager, says its not supported (unfortunately).

http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2011/04/18/redesigned-plot-catalog-in-matlab-r2011a/

5th response at the bottom